# How to fetch number of clusters for KMeans from clusteval python library

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm using clusteval python library to fetch the number of clusters but it was a process so I couldn't store the data. How to save the clusters values to a variable?

```
[clusteval] >Fit using agglomerative with metric: euclidean, and linkage: ward
[clusteval] >Evaluate using silhouette.
100%|██████████| 23/23 [00:00<00:00, 77.07it/s]
[clusteval] >Compute dendrogram threshold.
[clusteval] >Optimal number clusters detected: [3].
[clusteval] >Fin.
[clusteval] >Plotting the dendrogram with optimized settings: metric=euclidean, linkage=ward, max_d=197.613. Be patient now..
[clusteval] >Compute cluster labels.
[clusteval] >Estimated number of n_clusters: 3, average silhouette_score=0.897
```